# How To Add More Class after This condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

The origin script, work fine if I only add one class:

```
    function check_btn_charge() {
        if (parseInt(jQuery(".total-change-price").text()) >= 0) {
            jQuery(".btn-action-save-charge"+"&nbsp;"+"btn-danger").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            jQuery(".btn-action-save-charge"+"&nbsp;"+"btn-danger").prop("disabled", false);   
        }
    }
```

And I've tried to add more class in this condition using plus (+) sign and space character as separate class, like in the script below but not working :

```
    function check_btn_charge() {
        if (parseInt(jQuery(".total-change-price").text()) >= 0) {
            jQuery(".btn-action-save-charge").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            jQuery(".btn-action-save-charge").prop("disabled", false);   
        }
    }
```

what should I do to this script so that working well?

Comment: Your codes are mixed. And `&nbsp;` is not a space - it's string `&nbsp`. If you want space - here it is `' '`

Comment: could you explain the detailed in my script? 
is the code should be this ? ` jQuery(".btn-action-save-charge"+' '+"btn-danger").prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: Separate different classes/selectors with a comma `,` just like in CSS... Also `btn-danger` is missing a leading dot `.` it should be `jQuery(".btn-active-save-charge, .btn-danger")`

Comment: Great, it's working fine.. Thank you @Aziz and All :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select an element with both classes 'myClass1' and 'myClass2':

```
jQuery('.myClass1.myClass2')
```

If you want to select elements with one of the classes 'myClass1' or 'myClass2':

```
jQuery('.myClass1, .myClass2')
```

More than two classes follows the same rules.

[More info](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Mojtaba , your suggestions was helped me :)

Comment: @Ferdian, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure JavaScript equivalent for those disliking jQuery:

```
var and = document.querySelectorAll(".one.two");
var or = document.querySelectorAll(".one, .two");
var xor = document.querySelectorAll(".one:not(.two), .two:not(.one)");
var nor = document.querySelectorAll("button:not(.one):not(.two)");
```

[See it in action on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p2zxyzn/)